# struts 2 redirect java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: struts2

I'm creating a forum in my [web app](http://www.buscocolegio.com). I have the main page where I show all topics and buttons to search and create new threads. If the user clicks this last button I show a form to enter the data of the new topic. When the user clicks submit, I store this new thread in DB and then I redirect to the action that shows the main page:

```
< action name="showForum" class="es.busco.colegio.actions.ForumAction" method="show">
    < result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/forum.jsp< /result>
< /action>

< action name="newTopic" class="es.busco.colegio.actions.ForumAction" method="newTopic">
    < result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/newTopic.jsp< /result>
< /action>

< action name="createTopic" class="es.busco.colegio.actions.Forumction" method="insert">
    < result name="success" type="redirect">http://www.buscocolegio.com/Colegio/showForum.action< /result>
</ action>
```

The problem is the new topic is inserted twice in DB and in the logs `java.lang.IllegalStateException`

when I debug i see after executing the service call than inserts the object in BD, the program execution comes back to the begining of the method, that's why it's being inserted twice:

```
try{
        Date d=new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        String s=sdf.format(d);         
        Date d1=sdf.parse(s);
        topic.setDate(d1);
        topic.setText(topic.getText().replaceAll("\n", "<br>"));
        topicService.createTopic(topic);
    }catch (Exception ex){
        logger.error("Error: "+ex,ex);
        return Action.ERROR;
    }
    return Action.SUCCESS;
}
```

so after executing topicService.createTopic(topic); it comes back to Date d=new Date();

anybody knows why???

Comment: have you tried to debug the application to see why this is happening.without any insight of your code its hard to help you out.

Comment: moreover, it only happens on IE, not on Firefox nor Chrome...

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure without seeing your jsp code if this is what is happening or not, but I actually did have the issue of an action executing twice in IE and only once in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera.

One of our engineers had added on onclick event to a form submit button that would make the button disappear when clicked.  BUT, he also included a `document.forms[0].submit();` call in the javascript.  In IE *only*, this was causing the action to be executed twice.

So, be sure and check that you aren't accidentally submitting the form twice by calling a javascript submit on top of a normal HTML `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />`.